# When I copy and paste a feature, why does some of the attributes fields show null?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes, copy, null

I work on some maps representing administrative-territorial units in Roumania during 1990-2016. So, for every year that are associate with modifications in those units, I must realize a map. 
I downloaded a shp for 2016, and then I merged the features for representing the situation of 1990. 
In 2000, it has been established two new units. So, I copied these two features from 2016 shp and paste on 1990. 
But, after I did it, some attribute fields for these two copied features appear as null, even in the first layer (shp-2016), the values are shown.[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest that the fields coming up null differ in some important way (type, length etc.).

Comment: What are the source and destination file types? shapefile? geodatabase? Also, check to see if some of the fields have a default value, or if they have a default value.

Answer (score 1):

I see what the problem is. The fields have different names. Look at the field F2000total019 and you will note that in the other attribute table the name of the field contain an extra 0.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, and it contains a question. It would be better to rewrite the question to focus on the root issue and ask that question.

Comment: Vince- Ok, I deleted the question.